# Bootstrap Form Not Flowing Naturally

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 using the [horizontal form code structure](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal), and I cannot get the form itself to stay pushed to the natural top of the page (just below the title) except for the first field. There are no additional tags between each DIV block for the label/form elements. I tried placing `<br clear="all">` before the first form field group but that only pushed all the form fields down.

[Here is the form page](http://www.proppedupcreations.com/index.php?new=1&page=commissions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The container-navigation element is pushing the rest of the form down.  It's being floated to the left, but the container-content element sitting next to it is not floated.

Why don't you use the Boostrap grid system to setup the site?

Anyway, if you apply these styles to the #container-content:

```
/* padding-left: 143px; */
max-width: 1960px;
float: left;
width: 833px;
```

It seems to work OK, note that you need to get rid of the padding-left.

But as I said before, use the grid system to set up the navigation and the container-content.

Comment: I retrofitted bootstrap into this site, which explains some of the coding inconsistencies.